# Generically finite in co-dimension two

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be an $n$ dimensional complex normal projective variety. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, and $V\subset H^0(X,L)^{\vee}$ an $n+1$ dimensional linear system. Assume that the rational map
$$
f\colon X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}V
$$
is dominant. In particular, it is generically finite; so there exists an open dense subset $U$ of $\mathbb{P}V$ such that for every closed point $p$ of $U$ the fibre $f^{-1}(p)$ is zero dimensional. Now, it could be that for closed points outside $U$ the fibre is not zero dimensional.

I would like to give the following definition. I want to say that $f$ is generically finite in codimension two if the complement of $U$ has codimension at least three. In other words, for any codimension two linear subspace $H$ of $\mathbb{P}V$, the map $f$ restricted to $\overline{f^{-1}(H)}$ is generically finite.

Is there any characterization of such a property for generically finite maps? Do you know any reference where this situation has been considered?

(If it helps, one could assume $L$ ample. However, if one assumes that the map $f$ is regular, then the question become trivial, and I am definitely interested in the case where there is base locus)

Comment: I guess if the map $f$ is not generically finite over some divisor $D$ then $\dim f^{-1}(D) = \dim P(V) = \dim X$, which is impossible if $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Sasha you are right, sorry!! I meant codimension two.

Comment: What do you mean by saying the question is trivial when $f$ is regular?

Comment: @Sasha If the map is regular for every geometric point $p$ in $\mathbb{P}V$ the fibre $f^{-1}(p)$ is a zero dimensional scheme of lenght the degree of $L$. I think.

Comment: To compute the fibre over a point you have to intersect $n$ divisor in the linear system $V$. Assume their intersection contains a curve $C$. Take another divisor $D$. Then, this curve can not intersect $D$, because there is no base locus. On the other hand, being $L$ ample the intersection between $C$ and $D$ has to be non-empty. (If $L$ is not ample, at least this gives a precise descritpion of the positive dimensional fibres, as curves with zero $L$-degree)

Comment: Of course not, imagine for instance that $X$ is the blowup of $P(V)$ with center in a codimension 2 subvariety $Z$.

Comment: In this case the line bundle is not ample on $X$